# Compton Scattering - On the equivalence of the Klein-Nishina formula (and on the demonstration to go from one to the other)

Tags: scattering, education, scattering-cross-section

A stupid question about the Compton scattering and in particular the Klein Nishina formula.
I'm not sure I can find, if it exists, an equivalence between the three following formulas. (and what's the procedure to jump from one to the others)

I guess that the Einstein-Planck formula and the trigonometric relation on sine squared ($\cos^{2} + \sin^{2} = 1$) might help. As for the rest, I'm a bit lost.

Does anyone have a solution?
Thanks for your feedback.

*A little computer scientist who a bit confused in the vast world of diffusion physics.*

Formula 1: solved according to @DavidBailey 's answer
From "Xu, D., et Z. He. « Gamma-Ray Energy-Imaging Integrated Spectral Deconvolution ». 2007"
$$
\dfrac{\text{d}\sigma_{c}({E}_{0})}{\text{d}\Omega}\Bigg\rvert_{{E}_{1}} =\dfrac{r_{0}^{2}}{2} \frac{\left(1+\cos^{2} \beta\right)[1+\gamma(1-\cos \beta)]+\gamma^{2}(1-\cos \beta)^{2}}{[1+\gamma(1-\cos \beta)]^{3}},\quad\gamma = \dfrac{{E}_{0}}{m_{e}c^{2}}
$$

Formula 2:
From [Lojacono.X PhD thesis](https://theses.hal.science/tel-01081066) "Image reconstruction for Compton camera with application to hadrontherapy" (page 25)  with ${E}_{\gamma}$ (resp. ${E}_{\gamma}^{\prime}$) is the incident (resp. scattered) photon energy

$$K(\beta,{E}_{\gamma}) = \dfrac{r_{0}^{2}}{2} \left(
        \dfrac{{E}_{\gamma}^{\prime} }{{E}_{\gamma} }
    \right)^{2}
    \left(
        \dfrac{{E}_{\gamma}^{\prime} }{{E}_{\gamma}} + \dfrac{{E}_{\gamma}}{{E}_{\gamma}^{\prime} } - \sin^{2} \beta
    \right)
    \quad \text{ with } r_{0} = \dfrac{e^{2}}{4\pi\varepsilon_{0}m_{e}c^{2}}$$
$K(\beta,{E}_{\gamma})$ is a shortcut to express the the Compton scattering cross-section.

Formula 3: solved according to @DavidBailey 's answer
From "Knoll, Glenn F. Radiation detection and measurement. 4th ed, John Wiley, 2010." and "Lehner, C. E., et al. « $4\pi$ Compton imaging using a 3-D position-sensitive CdZnTe detector via weighted list-mode maximum likelihood » 2004".

$$
    \dfrac{\text{d} \sigma}{\text{d} \Omega} =
    Z r_{0}^{2}
    \left(
        \dfrac{1}{1+\gamma(1-\cos\beta)}
    \right)^{2}
    \left(
        \dfrac{1+\cos^{2}\beta}{2}
    \right)
    \left(
        1+ \dfrac{\gamma^{2}(1-\cos(\beta)^{2})}{(1+\cos^{2} \beta)\left(1+\gamma(1-\cos\beta)\right)}
    \right)
    ,\quad \gamma = \dfrac{h \nu}{m_{e}c^{2}}
$$

Specifically, in Lehner2004, the elimination of the $Z r_{0}^{2}$ term can be explained using the LM-MLEM algorithm in which the latter term appears in both the numerators and denominators of the normalised correction factor.

Extra question: Formula 4
From " Sauve, A. C., et al. « 3D image reconstruction for a Compton SPECT camera model » 2004 ":

\begin{align}
    \dfrac{\text{d} \sigma}{\text{d} \Omega} &= 
    \dfrac{\overbrace{0.572}^{??}}{{E}_{\gamma}}
    \left[
        1 + \left(2-\dfrac{{E}_{\gamma}}{\varepsilon}\right)^{2} + \left(1-\dfrac{{E}_{\gamma}}{\varepsilon}\right)^{2} \dfrac{\varepsilon}{{E}_{\gamma}}
    \right]
    ,\quad \varepsilon = \dfrac{{E}_{\gamma}}{1+\alpha(1-\cos \beta)}
    ,\quad \alpha = \dfrac{{E}_{\gamma}}{m_{e}c^{2}}
    ,\quad m_{e}c^{2} = 511~\text{keV} 
\end{align}

I don't understand where the value 0.572 comes from ..

Comment: Welcome @Imbda_ML to Physics Stack Exchange.  You are more likely to get help if you give links to where you took the three equations from.  Some clarification might also help, e.g. What is $E_1$ in equation 1? What is $K(\beta,{E}_{\gamma})$? Isn't $\alpha$ in equation 3 the same quantity as $\gamma$ in equation 1, in which case simple rearrangement of equation 3 gives equation 1. The only difference being that equation 1 if for one electron, and equation 3 is for the $Z$ electrons in an atom with atomic number $Z$.

Comment: Hello @DavidBailey , 
Thank you for your answers, which enabled me to go from equation 1 to 3. 
Given your answers, I understand better and I was naive enough not to see the direct relationship between the two equations. 
What remains is the transition, probably just as trivial, from equation 1 (or 3 for multiple electrons) to equation 2. 
I'll take your advice and add the sources where I found the expressions. 
Thanks again for your feedback. 
M.